# Update Gradle Plugin to Version 3.2.0 or higher

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to generate signed bundle for my flutter app but it is giving me an error to update gradle version. My current gradle version is already above v3.2.0. Any solutions ?

[image: Error Image]

This my **build.gradle** file

[image: build.gradle]

Comment: did you find anything for the same?